# What does a semicolon outside of curly braces do?

Tags: css

This has had me tearing my hair out for an hour:

```
div {
  key: value;
  ...
};

img {
  key: value;
  ...
}
```

(Note the semicolon after the curly brace).  None of the styling for `img`s was showing up ... finally I noticed the semicolon and removed it -- voila!  it all works as expected.

The question:  **what does a *;* outside of curly braces mean?**

Comment: I'd say it mean nothing, it is probably a typo by someone who is used to something like javascript, php, c# or you name it. The problem is that it will interfere with the rest of your CSS.

Comment: Chrome rejects the next rule without a warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means it is invalid CSS, the [CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) would tell you that.

Answer (score 8):

> what does a ; outside of curly braces mean?

*Invalid syntax.*

That's why the parser stopped there and didn't pick up any of the style rules below (e.g. `img`). [Validate](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input) it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is valid CSS, so behaviour in different browsers may vary.

If you use a CSS validator it should show up these sort of issues for you.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS parser probably encountered an error, and just refused to parse the rest of the file, but allow to use what it successfully parsed.